# Extension methods in a class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, extension-methods, class-library

I've implemented some extension methods and put those in separate Class Library project.

Imagine I have a simple extension method like this in class library called **`MD.Utility`**:

```
namespace MD.Utility
{
    public static class ExtenMethods
    {
        public static bool IsValidEmailAddress(this string s)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$");
            return regex.IsMatch(s);
        }
    } 
}
```

But nowhere in the web app like the `App_code` folder or the WebFroms code-behind page can I use this extension method. If I do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MD.Utility;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = "Someone@Somewhere.com";
        if (email.IsValidEmailAddress())
        {
            //To do 
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't recognize `IsValidEmailAddress()` and there's even no IntelliSense support.

While if I put my extension method in the `App_Code` folder, it's usable in  another `.cs` files in the `App_code` folder or the WebForms code-behind pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you remember to add a reference to your class library in the web project ?

You will need that. Other than that, your code looks fine, and should work.

Comment: There is a reference to classLibrary Project , But i don't know why the Dll don't Update when i rebuild solution , And if i try to Add Reference Again , it prompt that there is already a refrence , When you said It's should be work , I deleted Dlls  and added reference again and that worked . Thanks driis . Do you know why my Dll doesn't update automatically ?

Comment: That sounds weird. One other thing to check, is that the project is set to build for your current build configuration. On your toolbar you have a dropdown for switching between configurations (debug, release). The last element in that dropdown will bring up a dialog, where you can select or deselect projects for building in the various build configurations.

Comment: @Mostafa, you may have been building your library DLL to a different directory than the one you referenced.

Answer (score 2):

If changes are not getting recompiled when you do a solution rebuild, then it could be the type of reference you are using.  If the MD.Utility project is in your web project solution, you should make the reference a "Project Reference."  That will cause the build to consider that code as a dependency and therefore rebuild it when you change something.  If you just include it as a DLL, then the DLL is considered external and the build will not consider it, even if it is in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by making the extension module public. 
This post may be helpful:
[Extension methods in referenced assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724891/extension-methods-in-referenced-assemblies)

Comment: Yes, it must be Public. That's not the default, strangely.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the assembly to the references, what fixed it for me was to explicitly adding it to the file "using MD.Utility".

Comment: +1. Thanks this solved it for me. Using .NET Core 3.1 with C#. I had to add \@using to the template to use the IsAjax() method. Forgive my sins for I'll post code here: \@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor; \@using Midas.Extensions; \@if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.IsAjax()) { <span>Only worked after using Midas.Extensions;</span> }

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this can occur if the Assembly Name and Namespace of the consuming project are the same and the Common library has the same Namespace.

Seems that the compiler gets confused. Try changing them.

As noted elsewhere, you need to add the Common library to each consuming project. And the Module containing the Extension(s) in the Common library **must** be marked `Public`. Unlike Classes, `Public` isn't the default scope for Modules. No idea why.