# Extension methods in referenced assemblies?

Tags: .net, vb.net, extension-methods

If I try to call my extension method which is defined like this:

```
Module LinqExtensions
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToSortableBindingList(Of TSource)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of TSource)) As IBindingList
    If (source Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("source")
    End If
    Return New SortableBindingList(Of TSource)(New List(Of TSource)(source))
End Function
End Module
```

by calling

```
   Dim sss As String()
   sss.AsEnumerable.ToSortableBindingList()
```

it gives an error "ToSortableBindingList is not a member of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)".

Note: Intellisense autocompletes after the last period! If I try to call context.TestTable.AsEnumerable.ToSortableBindingList (TestTable is a pure EF4 generated class) it not even shows up with intellisense. I don't get why. What's wrong with the extension method declaration "ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of TSource)"?

### *********************************** EDIT ********************************

Ok, to clarify what's happening I'd like to provide some additional info. 
I can track down the problem to the following:

Scenario:

Assembly1 (root namespace "myapp"):

```
...
     <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
        Public Function ToTest(ByVal source As String) As String
            Return ""
        End Function
...
```

'Calling works:

```
...
Dim a as string
a.ToTest()
...
```

Assembly2: 
(Reference to Assembly1 included)

'Calling does not work:

```
imports myapp
...
Dim a as string
a.ToTest()
```

Comment: Note that it seems to be a problem with my namespace. The extension method resides in a different project with a different namespace which I import as usual (I can see all other methods with intellisense!)

Comment: Yes, for extension methods to work, they must be in the scope - that's how compiler (and intellisense) search for them. I will advise you to add your comment as an answer.

Comment: It is not the answer because I added this namespace already (therefore intellisense is working but nevertheless it underlines the call and is giving the error I already reported)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your namespace "myapp" cannot directly contain the function "ToTest", there is a Module defined there.
Try

```
Imports myapp.LinqExtensions
```

and make sure it is a Public Module

Comment: I can't import the module (an error is showing up in the IDE). I think this is because modules implicitly import their names into the current namespace.

Comment: did you define the module as a Public Module? If not it would not be accessible from another assembly.

Comment: You're absolutely right. If look closely enough I see that "public" is indeed missing... now it's working. Thank you very much!