# How to assemble assemblies?

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my .aspx file I have:

```
<%@ assembly src="extensions.vb" %>
<%@ assembly src="debug.vb" %>
```

I need to be able to use the extensions defined in extensions.vb within my debug class in debug.vb but I am getting compiler error `<function name> is not a member of <object>` in debug.vb.  What am I doing wrong?

#### Edit: structure of the two assemblies:

extensions.vb:

```
Namespace MyNamespace

Public Module MyModule

...

End Module

End Namespace
```

debug.vb:

```
Imports MyNamespace ' Also tried Imports MyNamespace.MyModule

Class Debug

...

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this to work, I had to move the vb files to the application's App_Code folder and then import the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the namespace that contains extensions.vb in the source of debug.vb.

```
Imports MyNamespaceThatContainsExtensions
```

Comment: I tried that to no avail.  I edited my question and added the structure of the two files.

Comment: The module must be public. See the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724891/extension-methods-in-referenced-assemblies).

Comment: I went through that link but it looks like I'm still missing something.