# Add a namespace reference to ALL web application web pages in a different project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-webpages

I have a solution with three projects:

- **Project 1** - Reusable Logic/Methods (applicable to all other projects)
- **Project 2** - Web site
- **Project 3** - Web application (project 2 being converted to a web application)

In project 1 I have this code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace MyCompany

    Public Module DataExtensionMethods

        <Extension()> _
        Public Function SortByColumn(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal SortString As String) As DataTable
            ' Amazing stuff here...
            Return dt
        End Function

    End Module

End Namespace
```

In the old-fashioned Project 2 web site, this extension method was easily accessible by adding the following to web.config:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" validateRequest="true" clientIDMode="AutoID">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MyCompany.DataExtensionMethods"/>
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

The extension method immediately became available on all references to a DataTable variable.

However, I cannot get this to work in Project 3 (web application) on an application-wide scale.

In each page, I can add this:

```
Imports MyCompany.DataExtensionMethods
```

This then makes the extension method available, but how do I achieve the same application-wide, without having to use Imports on each and every page?

In both Project 2 and 3 I have defined a reference to Project 1 using the Add Reference dialog.  The check box shows that still exists, but Project 3 cannot *see* Project 1's logic.  There seems to be loads of people seeing the [same behaviour with WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724891/extension-methods-in-referenced-assemblies), but not with web page apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB, you can set a globally imported namespace for the project by right clicking your project in the solution explorer, choosing properties.

On the references tab, at the bottom is the **Imported namespaces** section. You can add your namespace `MyCompany.DataExtensionMethods` there and it will act as if you're typed `Imports MyCompany.DataExtensionMethods` in all your source files.

[image]

Comment: OP is NOT asking how to add a reference to the project. His intention is to use members of MyCompany.DataExtensionMethods namespace without using `Imports MyCompany.DataExtensionMethods` (and implicitly, without using fully qualified names)

Comment: @haraman Yes, that's what the **Imported namespaces** section is for: creating a global namespace import.