# Web.config add namespace not applied at file level

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I am referencing a class library in a web application project (both in same solution).  Within the web pages of the web application, if I do this:

```
If MyValidation.CorrectEmailFormat(email) Then ...
```

...Visual Studio 2013 underlines the method, and suggests I import `MyCompany.EmailMethods` at the top of the page.  If I do the Import, the page compiles and the method works okay.

However, because these methods are used extensively across the application, I don't want to add them at page level every time.  So I headed for web.config, and did this:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MyCompany.EmailMethods" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

However, VS is *still* prompting me to perform the Import at the top of every page, and the method is not recognised in the page without doing this.  What I am doing wrong please?  I assumed from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zxswa8a5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [other sources](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/May/04/Adding-Default-Assemblies-Namespaces-and-Control-Prefixes-in-WebConfig) this was the correct way to achieve this.

Web application is ASP.Net web pages (4.6).

Comment: Is this Web Forms, or MVC?

Comment: Its Web forms, sorry I assumed that would be assumed from Web pages

Comment: [Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) is actually an entirely separate technology within ASP.NET. Web Pages uses Razor syntax to create pages. It's like [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) without controllers. So [Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) is important to specify.

Comment: Okay thanks. I've updated the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference must be added to the Imported Namespace as described in the following SO post

[add-a-namespace-reference-to-all-web-application-web-pages-in-a-different-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086067/add-a-namespace-reference-to-all-web-application-web-pages-in-a-different-projec/33086217#33086217)

It must be added in the project properties page at the bottom part titled **Imported Namespaces**

Comment: That question is mine. The references are not visible in that dialog, which is weird because VS recommends importing them!

Comment: Try manually adding the namespace name in the TextBox just before Add User Import button. I hope you gave a visit to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w4tctcf(v=vs.120).aspx . This page also says something about importing a namespace and a class in a namespace.

Comment: It worked!  Amazingly simple, but bizarre that VS doesn't see potential References like it does in code...

Answer (score 0):

The `<pages>` directive applies to ASPX files only.

You need to use the equivalent directive for Razor:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="MyCompany.EmailMethods" />
```

Comment: It's not razor it's Web forms that's why I don't understand why it is not working